# ListView jQueryMobile styles lost updating its contents

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Developing for Android using PhoneGap I am dynamically loading a ListView component with the data stored in the local database. When I save new settings information and pretend to get all the stored settings, the ListView is displaying everything right but looses the jQueryMobile styles.

This is the corresponding part of my html:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="pageIndex">

    <div data-role="content" id="cntMain">
        New settings attribute
        <div id="nameDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="name" data-inline="true">Name</label>
            <input id="name" type="text"></input>
        </div>
        <div id="valueDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="value" data-inline="true">Value</label>
            <input id="value" type="text" ></input>
        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="saveNewAttribute();" data-role="button">Save</a>
    </div> <!-- cntMain -->

    <div data-role="content" id="cntShow">
        Settings stored
        <ul id="settingsList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="b"></ul>
    </div> <!-- cntShow -->

</div>
```

And the js function called is:

```
function saveNewAttribute() {
    name = $('#name').val();
    value= $('#value').val();

    try {
        ... // Validations, saving new attribute,...

        // Get settings information (executeDBQuery is just a shortcut function for performing the query)
        executeDBQuery('SELECT * FROM SETTINGS', function(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            console.info('readed ' + len + ' rows');
            var html = '';
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var row = results.rows.item(i);
                html += '<li data-theme="b"><a href="#" onclick="editAttribute(' + row.id + ')" data-transition="slide">' +
                        '<h3>' + row.name + '</h3>' + 
                        '<p><strong>' + row.value + '</strong></p></a></li>';
            }
            console.info('Generated html=' + html);
            $('#settingsList').html(html);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e.message);
    }

    $('#cntMain').hide();
    $('#cntShow').show();
}
```

Does anyone know how could I refresh those jQueryMobile styles? Or maybe is there other way to dynamically load the ListView?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Soon after posting I found the solution... In case anyone is interested, just change the `$('#settingsList').html(html);` line to `$('#settingsList').html(html).listview('refresh');` in the js function.

Comment: If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added. For example:
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');

Note that the refresh() method only affects new nodes appended to a list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated, replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

Comment: Pablo: can you add your solution as an answer and mark is as accepted? Now the question is incorrectly marked as unanswered.

Comment: Posted. I could not add it before due to my low reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, in case anyone is interested. Write `$('#settingsList').html(html).listview('refresh');` instead of `$('#settingsList').html(html);`.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, after a DOM manipulation you must do a refresh :)